# Errno 31 Too many links - from pandas to_feather() data frame method

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Errno 31] Too many links
```

On this line of code:

```
df.to_feather(<path/to/file>)
```

From googling it I can only really find answers that refer to creating folders which I'm not doing in this instance.

Maybe worth mentioning that this code sits in a loop so the file is being constantly overwritten.

Any ideas on why it's happening?

---

Edit:

By way of some pseudo code for the loop as per the request in the comments:

```
while True:
    # return dataframe from database query
    df.to_feather(<path/to/file>)
```

Comment: Is your `path/to/file` a string?

Comment: Yep. It has been working fine just kicked into an error all of a sudden...

Comment: Can you share any more of your code? Or a simplified example of some sort?  As it is, the very limited information you've included makes it difficult to help.  What have you tried so far?  Maybe take the `df.to_feather()` out of the loop to confirm that it's working properly there and that the issue isn't related to the loop itself.

Comment: Hey. I've added in some simple pseudo code - the real code is database specific so probably wouldn't help. I figured this might be something to do with repeatedly overwriting the file or the fact that the file sits in a folder that syncs with google drive. I've reset the script now and it's working fine so I can't test removing the `to_feather()` :(

Answer (score 0):

This code actually isn't looping, so df.to_feather() isn't happening every time, but only once.

You should use a context manager, which will close the file once done, and this will let you reuse the file as you need.

```
from functools import partial

with open("sample.json") as file:
    df.to_feather(file)
```

Comment: Hi. This isn't correct. My pseudo code does loop - try `while True: print("printed")` and see what happens. The above code also doesn't work as `to_feather()` expects a string file path - this would pass a string of json...